# Is there a way to get Google Maps Shared Locations via API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google Maps has a wonderful [Contact Location Sharing](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816) feature. Does anyone know if this data is available programmatically? It would would be helpful to have access to mine and my wife's location for things like Home Automation or scripting

Answer (score 13):

Shared locations are not available via Google Maps API at the moment. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker for this:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62938530

You can add star to this feature request to express your interest and subscribe to future notifications from Google.

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down! I did some searching in the issue tracker, but couldn't find anything on mobile. Starred!

Comment: Has this answer changed now that shared locations are supported via Google Maps web page on regular PC or Unix browsers? (ie not just the android app)

Comment: Nope. The feature request is still having Assigned status.

Answer (score 7):

Unofficial Python library for this that's based on session cookies. Who knows how long that'll last:

https://github.com/costastf/locationsharinglib

Answer (score 5):

There is no official API, but someone created a cool Python package [locationsharinglib](https://pypi.org/project/locationsharinglib/) to extract this information from the Google Maps internal browser app.

Install

```
pip install locationsharinglib
```

Usage:

```py
from locationsharinglib import Service

cookies_file = 'cookies.txt'
google_email = '<your google username>@gmail.com'

service = Service(cookies_file=cookies_file, authenticating_account=google_email)

for person in service.get_all_people():
    print(person)
```

- **cookies.txt file**

  You need to sign out, and manually sign into your Google account. Then browse to google.com/maps and extract from your "google.com" cookies and save it as `cookies.txt`